# How to call a python script through an AJAX call?

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask

I have the following python script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flask import Flask, request, abort, jsonify
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
import MySQLdb
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('testFirst.html')

@app.route("/form_submit/", methods=['POST'])
    print ("outside function")
    def connect():
        import json
        dtb = request.select['value']    #i want the selected drop down value to be set here which will be used to connect to the database
        db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","",dtb)
        cursor =  db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM REPORT_SUITE")
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        json_return_value =[]

        for result in results:
            table_data = {'REPORTSUITE_ID' : result[0], 'REPORTSUITE_NAME' :     result[1], 'STAGING_DATABASE' : result[2], 'DWH_DATABASE' : result[3], 'TRANS_TABLE' : result[4]}
            json_return_value.append(table_data)
        print ("hi")
        print json.dumps(json_return_value)
        return json.dumps(json_return_value)    
    connect()    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

It renders the following html file:
    
    
    
         
        
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("button").click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                  url : "/form_submit/",
                  data : $('#databases').val(),
                  type : 'POST',
                  success : alert("Hi dear count ")
                });
                });
            });

```
<body>
    <select id ="databases">
        <option value = "">--Select From following--</option>
        <option value = "OMTSL_QBO">OMTSL_QBO</option>
        <option value = "OMTSL_SBG">OMTSL_SBG</option>
        <option value = "OMTSL_PTX">OMTSL_PTX</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <button type = "button"> Click Me!!</button>
    <div id ="placeholder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The HTML form should call the python script through an ajax call by passing the selected value from the drop down to the connect() method.

when i run main.py, i get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    connect()    
  File "main.py", line 16, in connect
    dtb = request.select['value']
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in   __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 20, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of request context')
RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

I do not know how to pass the drop down value to the called python fucntion. I tried to look for it but i have still not found the way to 
do it. Please help me through this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax uses HTTP, so you cant call a python script directly (unless you have specifically built your setup to work that way).

Your ajax should look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("button").click(function(){ $.ajax({ url : "/form_submit/", data : $('#databases').val(), type : 'POST', //success : alert("Hi "+ $('#databases').val()) success : alert("Hi dear count ") }); }); });
```

Then have a Flask function decorated with `@app.router('/form_submit/')` under which you would then handle the form data as per the Flask tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a separate "Python script". It should be another handler in your Flask app, with a route, which your Ajax script calls.

Answer (score 0):

In your second code, you're sending the call from ajax using POST, while in your Flask code you have

```
@app.route("/form_submit/", methods=['GET'])
```

Change this line into:

```
@app.route("/form_submit/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```